Overlay geom_boxplot() with hexagonal points showing raw data
I'm hoping this is fairly straightforward. I'm making a ggplot boxplot and then overlaying the boxplot with the raw data. However, instead of having the points appear as circles, I want them to be hexagons. It looks like ggplot has a handful of shape options, but none are hexagons. There appears to be a package (ggstar::geomstar()) that has hexagons (starshape = 6) but I can't figure out how to incorporate this into my code. Reproducible example below.
df <- data.frame(variable1 = c(1,3,6,3,5,2,2,4,1))
df

  variable1
1         1
2         3
3         6
4         3
5         5
6         2
7         2
8         4
9         1

ggplot(df, aes(x = 0, y = variable1)) +
  geom_boxplot(alpha = 0.5, outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.2), color = "red") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = NULL)



geom_star() can be used in place of geom_point():
library(ggplot2)
library(ggstar)

data <- data.frame(x = c(1, 3, 6, 3, 5, 2, 2, 4, 1))

ggplot(data, aes(0, x)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  ggstar::geom_star(
    position = position_jitter(width = 0.2), 
    color = "red", 
    fill = "red",
    starshape = "hexagon"
  )


Created on 2024-04-16 with reprex v2.1.0

Brilliant! I was getting some kind of error associated with not having an x variable when I tried this on my own. The provided code works perfectly.
